# ZonedTime fromJSON toJSON

Tags: haskell, aeson, servant

I am befuzzled by `Aeson` and `Servant` conversions of `ZonedTime`.

To my `Servant` app I give some time in the url: `.../2016-12-18T07:51:00+03:00/...`.

`Servant` easily converts it to `ZonedTime` with `... :> Capture "zt" ZonedTime :> ...`.

Then my app does some calculations and in json-response I want to give back to the client this and some other `ZonedTime`s — in case if client wants to give these times to my app again.

If input timezone was not zero `+0X:00` (X /= 0), then on the output I also get `+0X:00`, but if on input I give `.../2016-12-18T07:51:00+00:00/...`,  then in response I get `2016-12-18T07:51:00Z`. And if I try to feed this string to `Servant` again with `.../2016-12-18T07:51:00Z/...`, then `Servant` fails to convert it to `ZonedTime`. Actually is returns `HTTP 400 (Bad Request)`.

Why? What for?

Answer (score 0):

[ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is the standard textual representation for times used in JSON.  When the timezone is UTC, either "+00:00" or "Z" is a valid timezone suffix.  It looks like Aeson outputs times in ISO 8601 using the "Z" suffix if it's UTC and a "+xx:xx" suffix otherwise.  Unfortunately, Servant (actually, `Web.HttpApiData`) uses a naive method of parsing `ZonedTime` from URL pieces that doesn't permit the "Z" suffix.  If you parse a `UTCTime` instead, then it uses (and requires) the "Z" suffix.

You can define a newtype alias for `ZonedTime` as follows that handles both formats by trying to parse as a `ZonedTime` and -- failing that -- a `UTCTime` with conversion:

```
module ZonedTimeTest where

import Data.Time.LocalTime
import Servant.API

newtype ZonedTime' = ZonedTime' { getZonedTime :: ZonedTime }

instance FromHttpApiData ZonedTime' where
  parseUrlPiece u =     ZonedTime' <$> parseUrlPiece u            -- "...+xx:xx"
                    <!> ZonedTime' . fromUTC <$> parseUrlPiece u  -- "...Z"
    where fromUTC = utcToZonedTime utc
          infixl 3 <!>
          Left _ <!> y = y
          x      <!> _ = x
```

and then `Capture "zt" ZonedTime'` should handle both formats for you (though you'll need to unwrap the `ZonedTime'` to a `ZonedTime` where appropriate).

Comment: Aha. Clear. I will try first to make new capturing line with `utctime` instead of `zonedtime` and will see if Servant will manage with dispatching between two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

So, as soon as `...Z` notation is properly parsed by Servant as `UTCTime`, I just made another capturing line:

```
:<|> "myendpoint" :> Capture "zt" ZonedTime :> ...
:<|> "myendpoint" :> Capture "utct" UTCTime :> ...
```

And made corresponding handlers. With this literals with `+xx:xx` get taken as `ZonedTime` and go to one handler, and literals with `Z`  are taken by second line and go to second handler, that does the same as the first one, but converts `UTC` to `Zoned` on the fly.

---

**Update**

I came to understand, that the way, how my system is working leads to the fact, that in the URL I may be having different variations of string encoding time.

1. As a timezone may be `+03:00` or just `Z` if it is for UTC.
2. I may have fractional seconds like `2016-12-09T15:04:26.349857693845+05:00`

Standard `Capture` for `ZonedTime` doesn't understand neither `Z` as timezone, nor fractional seconds.

So I did somehow in the direction, as proposed in another Answer here.

I put only one Capturing line

```
"daymonth" :> Capture "zt" ZonedTime' :> Capture "fl" Double :> Get '[JSON] Value
```

and I make new type `ZonedTime'`, that is doing everything for me.

```
newtype ZonedTime' = ZonedTime' { unwrap :: ZonedTime }

instance FromHttpApiData ZonedTime' where
  parseUrlPiece text = Right zt
    where
      strRaw = unpack text
      str = subRegex (mkRegex "Z$") strRaw "+00:00"
      zt = ZonedTime' (parseTimeOrError False defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Q%z" str)
```

1. I deal with `Z` problem, substituting it with `+00:00`
2. Then I write parsing of the string manually, giving the format string, where `%Q` catches fractional part of seconds.